# problema al cambiar un proyecto android de pc

Tags: android, android-studio

Se me ha fastidiado un disco duro y consegui copiar el archivo del proyecto de milagro.

Lo he metido en un disco duro nuevo, instalando de nuevo android studio y me coge el proyecto pero me da errores que no consigo subsanar:

> Gradle DSL method not found : 'compile()' possible causes:
>
> -The project may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method  Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.1 and sync
>   project
>
> -The project may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> -The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin Apply Gradle plugin

Alguna idea de como recuperar el proyecto?

Comment: Agrega tu build.gradle....

Comment: Lo consegui solucionar borrando unas lineas del gradle. Gracias igualmente.

Comment: Excelente @miklotov agrega tu respuesta para que ayudes a otros desarrolladores!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

para ello debes descargar:

1. La versión de API que usa tu proyecto (desde el SDK Manager)
2. Una versión reciente de Gradle -> Ctrl + Alt + S -> Build, execution, deployment -> Gradle -> Use defatut Gradle wrapper (por defecto) ó puedes descargar de la pag oficial la última versión y seleccionar "use local gradle distribution"
3. Dependencias como las librerías support que usa tu proyecto y sus respectivas versiones(desde el SDK Manager)

---

Si esto no te vale, nos gustaría que dieras mas información como la configuración de tu build.gradle que parece tener algún problema.